# Database Fundamentals SQL

Tags: sql, erd

Show the orders that are partial shipments meaning that the quantity shipped is less than the quantity ordered. Display the SalesOrderNumber, PartID, Quantity Ordered and the Quantity Shipped in order by SalesOrderNumber, PartID.

Help: All of this information comes from two tables: SalesOrderPart and ShipmentPart. Use the WHERE statement to find the rows where the SalesOrderPart Quantity is greater than (use '>') the the ShipmentPart Quantity.

I have included an image of the ERD

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fASCR.png)

Comment: you can try using a [Join](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you!

```
SELECT sop.SalesOrderNumber, sop.PartID, sop.Quantity as Quantity_ordered, sp.Quantity as Quantity_shipped
FROM SalesOrder so
LEFT JOIN Shipment s ON s.SalesOrderNumber = so.SalesOrderNumber
LEFT JOIN SalesOrderPart sop ON sop.SalesOrderNumber = so.SalesOrderNumber
LEFT JOIN ShipmentPart sp ON sp.SalesOrderNumber = so.SalesOrderNumber
WHERE sop.Quantity > Quantity_shipped
GROUP BY 1,2
```